# Is there a way to use Qfield the same way as ESRIs Collector?

Tags: qfield

Is there a way to use Qfield the same way as ESRIs Collector? All I want to do i add shapefiles and a tile package of imagery

I'm new to QGIS and Qfield.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QField almost exactly like Collector, but there are a few minor differences. In QField there is no online stage. You set up your data in a normal QGIS project, package it using the QFieldSync plugin and transfer the result directly to your mobile device. Once you have set up the QFIeld project and transferred it to your device you can begin collection of data in a similar way to Collector. When preparing your data package you can add basemaps, raster and vector layers, but it's best to keep the amount to data to the minimum. There are lots of details and advice online at http://www.qfield.org.

If you are not familiar with QGIS, you may need to undertake some tutorials to get to grips with standard QGIS (although it will be relatively familiar if you already use ArcGIS) and run some tests on your QFIeld data to ensure it is set up how you prefer, but once set up correctly QField should operate in a similar way to Collector.

Comment: thank you Hannah. I have been tying to add rasters to Qfield by converting them to geopackages in GDAL but it can really handle them. do you know of a simpler way of doing this?